# NSNotificiation between objective-c class and swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have project with both objective-c classes and swift classes. Now I am at point where I need to post notification from objective-c class:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Here I present swift view controller
    CollectionViewController *cvc = [[CollectionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CollectionViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cvc];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BuildingReady" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:chosenBuilding, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"chosenBuilding", nil]]];
}
```

And I am listening to this notification in swift class:

```
import UIKit

@objc class CollectionViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getBuilding:", name: "BuildingReady", object: nil)
   }

   func getBuilding(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo: Dictionary<String, Building!> = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, Building!>

        self.chosenBuilding = userInfo["chosenBuilding"]
   }
```

Problem is that in swift class I never catch my notification (func `getBuilding` is never called).
Can there be problem that one object is objective-c class and second one is swift class?

Comment: Can you tried to change getBuilding to public func getBuilding?

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim I don't think that this is the problem. Because in different class I am posting notification to this (`CollectionViewController `) swift class and it catches the notification, then different func is called (written by same way as `getBuilding`) and there is no problem.

Comment: Maybe you should not use two string constants. Did you try to declare a single, public string constant?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BuildingReady" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:choosedBuilding, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"choosedBuilding", nil]]];
});
```

Comment: This was actually helpful. Sometimes when not posting the notification in the main thread, it gets ignored.